# The element position is invalid

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport 3.7.6*.

If you look at the image below, you will see a warning. The warning says:
**warning the element position is invalid**

Element reaches outside list contents height: y = 275, height = 30, list contents height = 30.

```xml
<componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="217" width="555" height="15" />
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical" ignoreWidth="false">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="deliverableProductsDataset" >
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{deliverableProducts})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="475" >

                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="23" y="275" width="257" height="30"/>
                                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>

                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your layout.

1. Element `jr:list` has height 15 and both elements `jr:listContents` and `textField` have height 30. Either increase `jr:list` height to 30 (or higher) or decrease `jr:listContents` and `textField` heights to 15 (or lower).
2. The position of the `textField` element should be relative to `jr:list`. So, since `jr:list` has height 15, you can't use y=275.

Here's a slightly modified version that works. Suit it to your needs:

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="0" y="217" width="555" height="30"/>
    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
        <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:listContents height="30" width="555">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="257" height="30"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </jr:listContents>
    </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```